# Why are shell builtins not found when using Kubectl exec

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl

I am making a bash script to copy files from a Kubernetes pod running Debian. When I include the following line:

```
kubectl --namespace "$namesp" exec "$pod" -c "$container" -- cd /var
```

it errors out:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "cd": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
command terminated with exit code 126
```

I also tried

```
kubectl --namespace "$namesp" exec "$pod" -c "$container" -- builtin
kubectl --namespace "$namesp" exec "$pod" -c "$container" -it -- cd /var
```

which gave the same result.

I was able to resolve the issue by changing the command to:

```
kubectl --namespace "$namesp" exec "$pod" -c "$container" -- /bin/bash -c "builtin"
```

Would love to understand why the first command(s) don't work and the latter one does. I would have thought that builtin commands are the one group of commands that *would* always be found, in contrast to commands that rely on the PATH environment variable.

Comment: ? The _shell_ builtin doesn't work because there is no _shell_. To use a shell builtin you have to run the shell, like bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kubectl exec` is used to execute an executable in a running container. The command has to be built into the container.

Neither `builtin` nor `cd` are valid executables in your container. Only `/bin/bash` is.

To execute a builtin shell command, you have to execute the shell and call it as the command argument like in your third example.